# Combine variables in order to create new one

Tags: spss

I need to have a new variable ethnicity.
The variables that I have now:
Dutch (if yes = 1, if no = 0)
Russian (if yes = 2, if no =0)

```
So it looks like that now:  
Russian    Dutch  
2            0  
0            1         
0            1  
2            0
```

How can I combine "Dutch"and "Russian"variables into new one Ethnicity"?

I want to have this result:

```
Ethnicity
2
1
1
2
```

I have tried to it with compute, but it was not successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple\basic\generic approach is:

```
if dutch=1 ethnicity=1.
if russian=2 ethnicity=2.
```

But if I understand the structure of your data right, this should also work:

```
compute ethnicity=sum(dutch, russian).
```

Comment: Thank you so much! With "if"has everything worked out

Comment: Glad to help! note I edited my second solution to match your edited question - should also work.